# What is the Future of Domain/Entity programming at Microsoft?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have currently been looking into Domain programming solutions and trying to predicate the future of the technology for my current customer.

Where is Microsoft going with this considering that there seems to be many different solutions depending on which technology your looking at. For example there is Entity Framework in .net and also there is the whole SQL Server Modelling solution that will be making its appearance in SQL Server. Part of the latter contains a language called M that seems to do the modelling and describing of entities in a decoupled way.

Where are they going with Visio?

Is there a reason that Microsoft seems to be avoiding the whole UML thing and reinventing the wheel, after looking at UML for a while now it seems to be turin complete and does the whole shooting match that could be decoupled from code and storage.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: My crystal ball says... dunno

Comment: Someone must know. Have I hit the problem on the head? No joined up thinking?

Comment: A bit of reading on SQL Server Modelling suggests that you can Load UML formatted files into the SQL Server modelling tools.

Comment: I did some research, M and Entity Framework are linked in some mysterious way. From what I gather the idea is that M will create the SQL Server Model (other databases are also valid) and feed into the Entity Framework. To take this even further it looks like you can use your favourite XSI UML tool and feed it into SQL Server Model. Damn thats a lot of area they are covering, is there anything left for the little guy? I suppose that Visio will join the party when the foundations are in place.

Comment: Makes me laugh though, I know that you can generate a sql Database from EF, when did the guys at Microsoft suddenly think, oops we are doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading around, Microsoft are tying things together in the future  M and Entity Framework are linked in some mysterious way. From what I gather the idea is that M will create the SQL Server Model (other databases are also valid) and feed into the Entity Framework. To take this even further it looks like you can use your favourite XSI UML tool and feed it into SQL Server Model.

So the disjointed stuff at present will come together.

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling Microsoft is betting on many horses in this race.

The support for POCOs in the latest Entity Framework release, to me, is a (good) sign that DDD is one of them.

With regards to UML. I actually downloaded Visio 2010 recently, and nothing has changed UML-wise the last ten years or so.

Visual Studio 2010, however, has gotten increased UML support (five diagram types supported).

Comment: I have not used VISO for years, but I do remember that it can do Database design with it that auto generates a Database schema. Not exactly Domain Driven, but not too far removed.